# Setup to quickly reload changes in a java web application in development using eclipse, maven, spring, hibernate, jsf

Tags: java, performance, maven, jsf

I'm developing a J2EE web application using **Eclipse IDE**, **Maven** and **Tomcat** as a web server.  I managed to configure it to launch and debug from eclipse and resolve dependencies from workspace and from Maven.

Building with Maven takes up to 120 sec (building each module, then deploying web-app using war:inplace), and reloading takes also up to 120 secs (**hibernate**, **spring**, **jsf**, etc)  It's a pain in the neck to reload full server each time I need to make a change in the project.

My project structure is a Maven "composite" project (in modules).  When I make a change to an existing method, I don't need to reload, but when I add 1 method, class, attribute, etc. I do need.

I've read that using JRebel is an option, but I can't afford it, so I wonder if there isn't any other way to quickly make changes to bussiness code without having to reload full app.

I've also setup eclipse to NOT automatically reload web-app and not to auto-sync web resources (otherwise my server detected changes and started reloading).  This is good to sync resources on demand (clicking publish button), but with Java code seems not to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566534/open-source-alternative-to-javarebel hace a look at it it might help :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll take a closer look ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Eclipse, use the M2Eclipse plugin from sonatype here:http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org. This will export the classes created by the Eclipse compiler directly to Tomcat. No need to run an "mvn clean compile" or "mvn clean package" command :D

Simply make a change to your code and Eclipse will publish the change instantly. If the change is to a classfile, you'll have to bounce Tomcat, but that takes all of about 4.83324523 seconds with Java 1.6 on a decent intel box.

Keep in mind though, if you're letting Eclipse do the builds, and you invoke a Maven build underneath it, Eclipse will be confused why the contents of the target folder changed. You can mitigate this by deleting the target folder, refreshing (f5) the project, and forcing a clean inside Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I do use M2Eclipse plugin but changes in a module don't get refreshed into webapp till I install module into local repository and then deploy webapp again.

If I have to delete target folder each time I need a build, things get worse.  Too many files to refresh, and more time to consume.  My webapp is a mean one :)

Apart from this, my webapp takes too long to init (hibernate, spring, etc) so I want to save as much time as posible on reloads.

I've tried adding project module dependencies as "linked projects" but changes are neither visible

Comment: See, that shouldn't be the case, trust me. Right now, I'm making a change to a war project and it's deployed straight to tomcat without a maven build taking place.

Is your project packaging a war? can you post your pom file?

Comment: Changing "webapp" files (facelets, css, img, etc) get published auto, with no need to reload, but when changing a class from a dependency jar, change does not refresh auto.
In the other hand, if I modify a class in the webapp project (there I have backbeans), depending on the change, I do see it with no reloading

Comment: snippet of dependencies in pom.xml

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tHb94jLnLJxg2o_vcZbgupGi1aakj6h0EDZYb2w6d38/edit?hl=es

Comment: module projects are into workspace and enable workspace resolution is enabled in Eclipse

Comment: Ah, well dynamic class reloading and 'no maven rebuild' are two completely separate topics. If you want dynamic class reloading, you have to use a framework that supports that (Tapestry does, but Tapestry stinks) or use JRebel.

My answer merely showed you how to avoid the Maven build step. You still have to bounce Tomcat, but there would be no 'mvn clean install' step.